# Modifying Solr Logging Library on Sitecore 8.2

Tags: solr

I'm trying to modify the log4j 1 library in Solr which is used with Sitecore 8.2. The plan is to either upgrade the Log4j to Log4j 2, or to use Java Logging instead using SLF4J.

Will this kind of change on Solr affects my sitecore? If no, how can i make sure it won't be affected?

Answer (score 1):

It will be good to follow the article https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1001391#Solution for update.

Once changes completed:

- You can verify that Solr log's are created successfully or not on Solr server
- You can verify Solr related functionalities on your application
- If you are behind the firewall then also you need to verify your servers and also Tanium tool can be used to identify the vulnerability https://community.tanium.com/s/article/How-Tanium-Can-Help-with-CVE-2021-44228-Log4Shellcan verify Solr related functionalities on your application
- There is another Solr vulnerability https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-45046 and I gone throw online resources and found that: *If you patched the log4j library code, that you are still exposed to 45046 (because the 45046 exploit is a result of the patch for 44228 not fully addresses all potential attacks) but if you've disabled lookups with the SOLR_OPTS parameter, then I believe that potentially eliminates the entire attack vector for both 44228 and 45046.You can verify Solr related functionalities on your application*
- In one of the Sitecore Slack thread @michael-west pointed out online resource [Huntress - Log4Shell](https://log4shell.huntress.com/). You can check this resource also for validation purpose.
- You can also check another resource [Impact of apache-log4j-cve-2021-44228 for your Sitecore Applications](https://sitecorebasics.wordpress.com/2021/12/14/impact-of-apache-log4j-cve-2021-44228-for-your-sitecore-applications/) for more details.